# Not Seeing Expected Output When Capturing Results of Command to Variable and Writing to Console in Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to understand what's going on here in Powershell (v2.0, if important).  I'm capturing the results of a command to a variable and when I write it to the console, I'm not getting the results I expect.  Everything but the output is functioning as expected.

This is an MCVE that acts in the same way as a script that I wrote.  I've just broken it down so that I can provide commentary on what's happening, where it's not working the way I think it should work, and what I think may be happening.

In this first snippet, I'm validating the status of the service `MyService`
on computer `svr0123`.  This gives the output that I'm expecting.

```
PS C:\Temp> Get-Service -Name MyService -CN svr0123

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  MyService          My_Service_Display_Name

PS C:\Temp>
```

In this second snippet, I'm doing the same, only assigning the output to
`$results` with the intention of restarting any stopped services.  Again, this
gives the output I'm expecting.

```
PS C:\Temp> $results = Get-Service -Name MyService -CN svr0123
PS C:\Temp> Write-Output $results

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  MyService          My_Service_Display_Name

PS C:\Temp>
```

Finally, I'm restarting the service, then writing the contents of `$results`
to the console.  This does **not** function as expected.  I would anticipate
that the contents of `$results` would be the same as the previous two outputs,
but instead I get:

```
PS C:\Temp> $results | Where { $_.Status -eq "Stopped" } | Set-Service -Status Running
PS C:\Temp> Write-Output $results

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  MyService          My_Service_Display_Name

PS C:\Temp>
```

This is incorrect **unless** each time I reference the contents of
`$results` it is calling the `Get-Service` command again, which is counterintuitive.  If that's the case, it
appears that I'm not storing the *output* of the command, but rather I'm
storing an *alias* to the command.  If I write the contents of `$results` to the console before doing the restart, everything outputs as expected.

This is a trivial fix, but I'm trying to understand the "Why" behind what I'm observing.  My questions are:

- Is this, in fact, what is occurring?  Where in the Powershell documentation
  can I learn more about this?
- If this is what is occurring, is there a way that I can just store the
  *output* so that I'm not incurring multiple calls?  It's trivial in this
  case, but my script will be used on a busy network and may at times have
  to query hundreds of servers in a given run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Get-Service -Name MyService -CN svr0123` it is returning a `ServiceController` object, not just the text of the output.

So, when you call this line:

```
$results = Get-Service -Name MyService -CN svr0123
```

`$results` is not just a string variable containing the output of the command. It is actually a variable of type `ServiceContoller`.

Run this to see:

```
$results.GetType()
```

You will get this:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                      BaseType
-------- -------- ----                      --------
True     False    ServiceController         System.ComponentModel.Component
```

So, the second time you execute `Write-Output $results`, the service has been started and the `$results` variable is displaying the current status of the service.

Answer (score 1):

I think it does not re-call `Get-Service` when you display the service object. I think the `$service` object has an internal state which is a text value, and when you pipe it to `Set-Service` that state value gets changed as well as the service being started/stopped.

Since trying to change it directly with `$service.Status = "Running"` generates an error because the property is read-only, this change could be happening through the service object's own `$service.Start()` and `$service.Stop()` methods found from `$service | get-member`

Supporting evidence from some quick tests:

- I `$service = get-service testsvc; $service` and see the state is Running, then I go to Control Panel and stop the service there, and the `$service` state does not change.
- I call `$service.Start()` directly to restart the service, and I get an exception (possibly because my PowerShell is not running as an Admin) so the service does not actually start running, however `$service.Status` does change (incorrectly) to say the service is running.

This way I get a disconnect between the reported status and the actual status is convincing me, and the way it seems implausible/impractical for every object to "know" how it was generated and arbitrarily re-run that code (what if it was a 30 minute query to generate it?) but I don't *know* for sure what the interactions are.

Comment: This would also make sense, as the `$results | ... | Set-Service -Status Running` line would then be operating on the service object, which (I assume) is what is then actually generating the call to restart the service on the remote machine?  Am I understanding this correctly?